# Hide an NSTextField in swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

How does one hide an `NSTextField` in Swift?

In Interface Builder, there is an option to make the view hidden.
However, I can't figure out how to control the hidden state programatically.

NSSecureTextField can be hidden simply by setting

```
secureTextField.controlView?.isHidden = true
```

How does one do this for a regular `NSTextField`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
textField.isHidden = true
```

that's really all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Why is that not included in the [API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextfield)?

Comment: I guess it's because `NSTextField` inherits from `NSControl`, which inherits from `NSView` which implements the `isHidden` property? It's a bit of a trek to find though!